# How to properly do JS condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I run this jQuery (1.8.3) code and always get the "in" alerted even when the length is greater than 1.

What I'm doing is dynamically adding elements to a menu and the if is to make sure this element doesn't exist yet.

I tried also `== 0` and `=== 0` but the result is the same...

Here is a JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mHhwq/4/

```
$(".sidebarit a.olink").click(function(event){
   iframe_url = $(this).attr("href");
   sidebar_id = '#' + iframe_url.replace(/[/.]/g, '');
   alert('sidebar_id: ' + sidebar_id);

   // create the sidebar if it doesn't exist
   if ($(sidebar_id).length < 1) {
      alert("in");
      $("#sidebar_nav ul").append('<li></li>');
      $("#sidebar_content").append('<div id="' + sidebar_id + '" style="display:none;"></div></div>');
   } else { alert("out"); }

   // don't follow the link
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

In FireBug I see the length equals 1 but still enters the block.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

My mistake was that I added the `#` at the wrong place...

Comment: Please provide the entire source code, and perhaps even the FireBug output.

Comment: What does the HTML look like?  What is the value of `sidebar_id`?  You're only giving us half the info.

Comment: What's the value of `$(sidebar_id)`?

Comment: You are basically claiming `if (1 < 1) {
    alert("in");
}` will produce an alert of `in`, which is not something that can be easily reproduced at least. You have to be making a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Sorry for lacking info, I've updated the question. hope there is enough now...

Comment: @Asad, When the page loads the `$(sidebar_id)` does not exist, but after the first click it exists, and in firebug when I point the mouse on the `.length` I get the value of `1` (before that it was correctly `0`).

Comment: Actually, it's not that helpful. What's the value of `iframe_url` and `sidebar_id`? What type of object is does `$(sidebar_id)` return? Can you reproduce your code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ "Create a new Fiddle - jsFiddle") for us to look at?

Comment: @SimonW The condition is checked when the value is 0. When an element has been added, the value is 1. What is the problem?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is as @JustinJohn details in his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13680583/783743) below. We may never know until we actually see the entire code.

Comment: I've added a js fiddle. The same happens there. I added an alert of the `.length` and for some reason it appears 0 there, though the ID exists...

Comment: The problem is as @JustinJohn predicted (I updated the fiddle to `sidebar_id.slice(1)`, which solves the problem): http://jsfiddle.net/mHhwq/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put alert inside `if stmt` as `alert($(sidebar_id).length)`.

And you are making a mistake in appending the `div` to`$("#sidebar_content")`.

Where `sidebar_id` is something like `#test` from `sidebar_id = '#' + iframe_url.replace(/[/.]/g, '');` and you are appending like `<div id= "#test"` there, where it should be `<div id= "test"`(No `#` symbol is requird for id).

Your code will results like

```
$("#sidebar_content").append('<div id="#test" style="display:none;"></div></div>');
```

Change to

```
$("#sidebar_content").append('<div id="test" style="display:none;"></div></div>');
```

Then try again.

Comment: +1 for noticing that the OP is assigning an id prefixed with `#` to the id attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You must not have more than one element with the same ID. jQuery takes just the first in such a case.

To prove this have such HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv">hello</div>
<div id="mydiv">world</div>
```

Then this code:

```
var myDiv = $("#mydiv");
alert("length: " + myDiv.length + ", contents: " + myDiv.html());​
```

[Test case](http://jsfiddle.net/RPShg/).

If you have more than one element you need to iterate, use class instead or alternatively make sure to have unique ID for each sidebar and take the one closest to the clicked element.

Comment: That is what I'm tring to avoid. that if it already exists the code in the if will be skipped.

Comment: You will have either 0 or 1 as the length, using jQuery I don't think you can know if there is more than 1 already.